# MacOSX cronjob item not executing

Tags: shell, osx-mountain-lion, cron

I've got the following entry in root's crontab, but it doesn't fire at all:

```
0 6 * * 1-5 /usr/sbin/zfs snapshot rpool@`date +"%m-%d-%y"`
```

I see nothing in the logs or mail related to it, either.

Perhaps the backticks and quotes are causing problems?

When running the command from the command line it creates the snapshot just fine:

```
% /usr/sbin/zfs snapshot rpool@`date +"%m-%d-%y"`
```

Your suggestions would be most appreciated.

The system is OSX Mountain Lion with ZEVO ZFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've learned that cron was interpreting the % as new lines, so the following works:

```
0 6 * * 1-5 /usr/sbin/zfs snapshot rpool@`date +"\%m-\%d-\%y"`
```